# Safe call operator - only call function if object is not null

Tags: c++, function

Is there something like following in c++:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls

I want to shorten calls like following:

```
int x = 0;
IPtr pClass(...);
if (pClass)
{
    pClass->...
    pClass->...
    x = pClass->function();
}
```

Any macro/language trick I can use to make this look like following pseudo code?

```
IPtr pClass(...);
pClass?->... // only call function if pClass != nil
pClass?->... // only call function if pClass != nil
int x = pClass?->function() | 0; // only call function if pClass != nil, otherwise assign 0 to x
```

**Edit - UseCase**

I develop a few plugins for another software and other plugins of myself may be available or not.

Most simple example would be a logging plugin, where I want to have a lot of logging calls all over in my code and want to log something only, if the logging module was loaded and is available. I get a pointer to the singleton logger module from the software my plugin is for. My code would be polluted by log lines like following:

```
if (logger)
{
    logger->log(...);
}
```

And it would be more beautiful and compact to make this a one liner without the if that is null safe...

Comment: `IPtr` obviously overloads the `->` operator. Why not do it in the overload? Or just write a "`SafeIPtr`"?

Comment: C++ does not have null-conditional pointer access. I think this is done on purposes: C++ designers don't want you to get too comfortable around pointers, because they want you to prefer references instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller An overload would not work, because `p->func(a->field)` expression when `p` is `nullptr` must not crash even if `a` is `nullptr`. Processing this in an overloaded operator would be too late.

Comment: Correct, overloading is no solution. I'm thinking about a macro that takes the object, function name and otpional parameters as a solution, I think this should be possible...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - The OP asked with regard to evaluating `pClass`. If they are willing to settle for a more limited solution, I think they can have it. I don't want to extrapolate about evaluating *every single* `->`.

Comment: @prom85 - If your problem is X, with a solution Y, then macros are almost certainly Z. Don't waste your time creating some ad-hoc mini-language with the preprocessor.

Comment: I made an edit to explain the use case a little more

Comment: Have you considered using the null object pattern, i.e. instead of having function objects that contain nothing, have function objects that contain the default action (do nothing, return 0, etc.)?

Comment: @StoryTeller It's not every single `->`, it's a basic evaluation of `->` overload. The idea of `?->` is that when the left side is `nullptr` the right side is not evaluated at all, which is impossible to do in an overload. You can't do it for the same reason that you cannot implement short-circuiting functionality of `&&` in an overload of operator `&`: C++ must evaluate both sides before calling your overload.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The problem with null object pattern is that the parameters are evaluated even if `log` is null object. Spending CPU cycles on computing throw-away values is something you want to avoid when the logging is turned off.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I know what the idea of `?->` is, I dabbled with C#. My point was that `IPtr` is obviously smart pointer like class, and with `pClass` being an object in scope, it *cannot be null*. Evaluating **it** is not the problem. And when coupled with Sebastian's suggestion of returning a "mock object", from `IPtr`'s overload, it could work. All depends on the OP's vision.

Comment: `IPtr` is just a normal pointer (name was just selected by chance) to an interface and this pointer can be `null`, the software I write plugins for will return `nil` if the corresponding plugin was not loaded...

Comment: @prom85 - Then you misled me. This is exactly why hiding pointer semantics is something one should not do. Your declaration looks just like a regular object of a class type.

Answer (score 6):

**Code style solution (The *RIGHT* solution)**

The design could be improved to solve this issue. When the `logger` plugin is not loaded, you shouldn't receive a `nullptr` but rather a dummy `logger` object that has an empty implementation.

Factories (especially ones creating global infrastructure objects) should not return `nullptr`.

**Smart pointer wrapper**

This is a **concept** you could use:

```
struct Object {
  void run() { std::cout << "run" << std::endl; }
  void stop() { std::cout << "stop" << std::endl; }
};

template < typename T >
struct safe_ptr : std::unique_ptr<T> {
  safe_ptr(T * ptr) : std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr ? ptr : &t) {}

  virtual ~safe_ptr() {
    if (::std::unique_ptr<T>::get() == &t)
      ::std::unique_ptr<T>::release();
  }

  using std::unique_ptr<T>::operator*;
  using std::unique_ptr<T>::operator->;

private:
  T t;
};

int main() {
  safe_ptr<Object> safe(nullptr);
  safe->run();
}
```

The `safe_ptr<T>` will use a valid pointer to an object if initialized using a `nullptr`.

You could of course improve this solution to work only with Objects that define a default fallback static object, e.g:

```
struct Object {
  void run() { std::cout << "run" << std::endl; }
  void stop() { std::cout << "stop" << std::endl; }

  static Object fallback;
};

Object Object::fallback;

template < typename T >
struct safe_ptr : std::unique_ptr<T> {
  safe_ptr(T * ptr) : std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr ? ptr : &T::fallback) {}

  virtual ~safe_ptr() {
    if (::std::unique_ptr<T>::get() == &T::fallback)
      ::std::unique_ptr<T>::release();
  }

  using std::unique_ptr<T>::operator*;
  using std::unique_ptr<T>::operator->;
};
```

This will avoid multiple allocations of the private `T t` and will allow a specific initialization of the `fallback` object.

Answer (score 2):

Not the solution you're suggesting, but since I personally find these "safe" call operators particularly hard to follow I'll suggest an alternative code style based on a lambda called on the spot:

```
int const x = [&] {
    IPtr const pClass = /*...*/;

    if(!pClass)
        return 0;

    pClass->/*...*/;
    pClass->/*...*/;
    return pClass->function();
}();
```

This gizmo is called an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) by Javascipt folks, and is incredibly useful to wrap complicated initializations with branching code paths.

Comment: I'd caution that one should not favor IIFE, when one can modify the objects c'tor.

Comment: @StoryTeller agreed -- that, or a factory function. IIFE's are for one-off needs :)